# поиск подстрок в массиве, состоящих из одинаковых букв

Tags: c++

предположим, у меня есть массив строк

```
{"abcv","ghav","bvac","vhag"}
```

мне нужно найти подстроки, которые состоят из одинаковых букв и сформировать из них пары

```
{"abcv","bvac"}
{"ghav","vhag"}
```

у меня никак не получается это сделать

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
int main()
{

   char String_Array[][11] = { "abcv","ghav","bvac","vhag" };
   char Result_Array[1][11];
   int k = 0;
   for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
   {
      for (int index_i = 0; index_i < 4; index_i++)
      {
          int j = 0;
          int specCnt = 0;
          while (String_Array[i][j] != '\0')
          {

             int index_j = 0;
             bool trigger = false;
             while (String_Array[index_i][index_j] != '\0')
             {
                if (String_Array[index_i][index_j] == String_Array[i][j])
                {
                    trigger = true;
                    break;
                }
                index_j++;
             }
             if (specCnt >= 0)
                if (trigger)
                    specCnt++;

             if (specCnt == strlen(String_Array[i]) && trigger)
             {
                strcpy_s(Result_Array[k], String_Array[i]);
                k++;
             }
             j++;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

как избавиться от проверки подстроки с самой собой и как составить эти пары?

Comment: У вас проблемы не только в этом. Вы выделяете память для одной строки - `char Result_Array[1][11];`, а пишете туда, как в массив строк (`strcpy_s(Result_Array[k], String_Array[i]);
                k++;`).

Comment: Поскольку @MBo по сути уже это сказал, не буду перебивать его ответ - такие задачи на анаграммы решаются с помощью упорядочения исходных строк и приведения их в канонический вид. раз уж у вас С++ - то я бы делал так https://ideone.com/XP1mMM

Comment: а я не совсем понял, что происходит вот здесь 
        for (const auto& p : m)
 {
  for (auto s : p.second)
   cout << s << " ";
  cout << "\n";
 }

Comment: Просто вывод всех анаграмм в отдельной строке. Они хранятся в векторе, который является значением в паре ключ/значение, хранящейся в `map`. Первый цикл - по отображению, второй - по вектору.

Comment: а где вот само их сравнение происходит?

Comment: А само сравнение при вставке - где `m[s].push_back(...)` - за кулисами, так сказать...

Comment: функция push_back() сама отсортирует их внутри?

Comment: разобрался, спасибо, можно еще один вопрос, 
for (const auto& p : m) почему используется ссылка на p ?

Comment: @user9431986  `push_back()` добавит "vhag" к списку (вектору), относящемуся к ключу "aghv"

Comment: @user9431986 `for (const auto& p : m)` позволяет обращаться к элементам контейнера, не создавая их копий (как происходит при обращении по значению)

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы не сверять элемент с собой же, используйте такие циклы:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
      for (int j = i + 1; j < 4; j++)
     {
```

(в данном случае этого может и не понадобиться)

Если **сортированные** строки (из `"vhag"` сделать `"aghv"`) совпадают, то исходные являются анаграммами

---

Поэтому можно: отсортировать символы в строках, составив структуры `{сортированная; исходная}`

Отсортировать массив структур по ключу сортированных строк

Пройтись по результату одним циклом, сравнивая только соседние структуры на равенство ключа

---

Как вариант - добавлять структуры в `map`, проверяя на наличие такого же ключа.

Comment: то есть, вы имеете ввиду, что можно отсортировать каждую подстроку, а потом найти из них одинаковые?

Comment: Да, сохраняя и исходные для вывода. Отредактировал, добавив более оптимальный алгоритм для больших массивов

Answer (score 0):

Что-то ваш вопрос очень похож на тестовое задание или лабораторку по информатике.

Ну вот например вот так можно отсортировать и сгруппировать в плюсах:

(тест) https://www.onlinegdb.com/r1psIgROX

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

string asort(string input) {
    sort(input.begin(), input.end());
    return input;
}

int main() {
    vector<string> strings = {"abcv","ghav","bvac","vhag"};
    map<string,vector<string>> results;
    results[asort(strings.at(0))].push_back(strings.at(0));
    for (int i=1; i<strings.size(); i++) {
        results[asort(strings.at(i))].push_back(strings.at(i));
    }
    for (auto it = results.begin(); it != results.end(); ++it ) {
        for(vector<string>::const_iterator str = it->second.begin(); str != it->second.end(); ++str) {
            cout << "" << *str << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Баги есть всегда и везде (исправления):

```
vector<string> strings = {"abcv","ghav","bvac","vhag"};
map<string,vector<string>> results;
for (auto string = strings.begin(); string != strings.end(); ++string) {
    results[asort(*string)].push_back(*string);
}
```